# Small chip (not really a crack) in marble shower threshold - leave it or seal it?

Tags: shower, marble, chip

This is a new build. Shower not yet used - waiting for the door to be installed. It's on the shower side unfortunately so it's definitely going to get wet. The pic doesn't do it complete justice, but the arrow is pointing to the chip. It does look like a couple other cracks are present but they are mostly visual. I can't get a fingernail in them really. Anyways - for the chip that's about 2mm deep at the edge, is it fine to leave or should I cover it with clear epoxy or what do you suggest? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you the builder or the new owner?

Comment: @JACK, I’m the owner of the home (posting on mobile now - hope the formatting was right…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enjoy your new home. If the chip/crack doesn't go all the way down and is just on the corner, it won't be a problem. If it's going to keep you awake at night or you have absolutely nothing to do, you can put a small drop of clear exopy, using a toothpick, on the cracks just to smooth out the edges.

Comment: ok good to know, thanks! yeah I didn't even notice it at first when the installers put it in. It blends right in - was just concerned if the daily barrage of water would cause trouble down the line

Answer (score 0):

Harmless, if it doesn't bother you aesthetically. It's not as if you are going to subject this stone to freeze/thaw cycles where ice might be able to break it further.

Comment: great, thank you!